# Which python library to use for qualitative analysis of survey data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis

I have a dataset of responses from around 300 people completing a questionaire. The questionaire dealt with user experiences and behaviour in public transport. We ran the survey for 3 bus companies. Most of the questions are "yes/no", "best among 3" or "worst among 3".

If possible, I want to build a model that will suggest the best company of the three, based on the answers. The questions are like, "Availability of a buses, reliability of buses, preferences of the user and physical maintenances of the bus.

I expect the model to analyse the data set and return the best bus company which will be easily available, clean and well maintained, reliable and the user will prefer it.

Also, answers to questions like "Which bus do you prefer?" should have more weight in decision making.

I am pretty new to machine learning and would appreciate suggestion on which algorithm to start with to train the model.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to do all the cleansing of data such as removing null values and data validation.

Secondly, if you need to visualise your data, the more popular choices would be seaborn or matplotlib.

Lastly, for your model, since its machine learning and not deep learning, [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) is a great library to train your model

I would recommend that you acquire more data as 300 is not sufficient. Not in the world of machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

I may add also that you can also use NLP libraries like BERT or NLTK, they have pretrained models also.

At the preprocesing stage, as you have a classification issue, be careful to balance your data.